# jQuery UI .tabs() Contentless tab?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I want to have a set of tabs. In each tab header, there is a piece of text and a button that removes the tab it belonds to on click. And after the tab headers (`<li>`), i would like to have an extra button that creates a new tab on click. For example :

```
<div class="TabSet">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabContent0">TEXT<button class="RemTab">x</button></a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabContent1">TEXT<button class="RemTab">x</button></a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabContent2">TEXT<button class="RemTab">x</button></a></li>
        <li><button class="AddTab">+</button></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabContent0">CONTENT</div>
    <div id="tabContent1">CONTENT</div>
    <div id="tabContent2">CONTENT</div>
</div>
```

Does jQueryUI .tabs() work if i have more `<li>` elements than `<div>` elements ? If not, is there a clear work around ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: "Work around"? You mean like doing it correctly by adding both a new `<li>` and corresponding `<div>`? What do you expect to do with the add button?

Comment: Well... you know... add.

Comment: @Ian, i think the OP simply wants to add another tab with a content section when you click the add button.  i assume that he will then also add other controls into the newly created tab content.

Comment: Right, so why wouldn't you add a new `<li>`, and then a corresponding `<div>`?

Comment: Yes, using .tabs('refresh')

Comment: Because i don't want the add button to be considered as a tab.

Comment: Yes yes, I'm realizing that now. Sorry for the confusion! I didn't realize you were talking about the extra/lone `<li>` because of the add button

Comment: Should i unwrap the `<li>` of the button ? Will .tabs() handle it ?

Comment: Oh, right, you want to add a "button" but not a tab with a button next to the last tab?  Kinda tricky because if it's not a tab then it wont follow the rules such as wrapping etc

Comment: You mean like this? http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#manipulation it's already done as an example... you just need to move the button functionality to the last tab and have the add tab always add the tab before the last tab.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the answer to "does this work" is always "try it and see".

Second, it's possible to fake an "empty" tab by intercepting and cancelling the [`beforeActivate`](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#event-beforeActivate) event. Before cancelling your event handler would modify the DOM appropriately to add a new tab and call the [`refresh`](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#method-refresh) method to update the UI.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Isn't there a way to just make .tabs() ignore it ? By removing the `<li>` for example ? I would like to keep it as simple as possible.

Comment: Actually i tried, and removing the <li> around button works, .tabs() seem to ignore the button.

Comment: @Virus721: To be frank I 'd probably go with a tab and without a button in order to take advantage of the jQuery UI visual styles for free. Here's an [example on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nmAT4/).

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I do: I insert a "close button" on the active tab:

```
var $tabs = $('#tabs').tabs({
    heightStyle: 'content',
    activate: function(event, ui) {

        var $activeTab = $tabs.find('.ui-tabs-active');

        // Remove all the close buttons
        $('.ui-tabs-tab i.tabCloser').remove();

        var $thisCloseTabLink = $('<i class="icon-cancel-circled tabCloser">')
            .hover(
                function() {
                    $(this).addClass('icon-cancel-circled-outline');
                }, function() {
                    $(this).removeClass('icon-cancel-circled-outline');
                }
            );

        // Add the close button
        $activeTab.append($thisCloseTabLink);
    }

});
```